# error acessing WSDL from browser

Tags: java, web-services, soap, wsdl, axis

I have this Web service code (first time) that I am troubleshooting. I am not able to test the web service on the browser using URL. I see the operations on the browser but when I click on them they are throwing 404 error.

The link next to them does not look right. I know they are coming from server-config.wsdd file. Don't know how this wsdd got geerated in the first palce.Not sure what need to be changed to resolve the 404 error. On clicking on the web service URL, I see below message

`http//localhost:8080/testWS/EmpDeptWebService`

And now Some Services

`AdminService(wsdl)
Version(wsdl)
EmpDeptWebService(wsdl-http//localhost:8080/testWS/services/EmpDeptWebService?wsdl)`

None of the wsdl links work. There is no services folder? Not sure how its generating the URL.

Comment: What application Server are you using ??

Comment: server is tomcat server

Comment: Wsdl is web service definition language file in XML format. It is generated in soap server side and shared with client to generate their stub codes. Server and client may not be implemented in same programming language.